# Using checkbox yo update MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have been searching round the internet for days on this matter but I keep coming up against a brick wall.

What I have is a table full of checkboxes inside an admin area acting as a monthly "to-do" list. It's essentially a worksheet of 30 or so things to do each month that must be checked off each month and notes added if applicable.

I have managed to get the checkboxes to update via mysql and be shown somewhere as a list of ticks. I simply did this my setting the value to 1 and on submission it updates the sql table.

I have to cover my bases here and also offer the option to un-tick items if they have been ticked b y mistake. But I cant figure out how this is done.

Below is my checking code... any help on this matter would be great.

```
    <?php   
$currentTask = '';
echo "<tr class='tr'>";
while ($seolistRow = mysql_fetch_array($seolistRes)) {
    $taskValue = $seolistRow["taskValue"];
    $worksheetID = $seolistRow["worksheetID"];
    $taskName = $seolistRow["taskName"];
    $taskInfo = $seolistRow["taskInfo"];

    if ($taskValue == 1) {
            $taskDone = "<input type='checkbox' value='1' class='checkbox' name='checkbox".$worksheetID."' id=checkbox'".$worksheetID."' checked='checked' /><div class='taskinfo'>".$taskInfo."</div>";
    }
    else {
            $taskDone = "<input type='checkbox' value='0' class='checkbox' name='checkbox".$worksheetID."' id='checkbox".$worksheetID."' />";
    }
    if ($currentTask != $taskName) {
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr class='tr'>";
        echo "<td class='task'>".$taskName."</td>";
    }
echo "<td class='tick'>".$taskDone."</td>";
$currentTask = $taskName;
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Edit:

When I save it to the DB i use the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {  
$item = $_POST;
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        $wsID = str_replace("checkbox","",$key);

        if (is_numeric($wsID)) {
            $updateWSQ = "UPDATE seo_work SET taskValue=$value WHERE worksheetID=$wsID AND userID=$userID";
            mysql_query($updateWSQ) or die(mysql_error());
            header("Location: worksheet.php?userID=$userID&action=success");
        }
    }
```

}

What I want it to do is when I check a checkbox and click submit, for it to save a the value in the db as 1. (this works for that) but when I uncheck the checkbox I want it to remove the value and replace it with 0.

this will then be displayed in a secure log in area for each customer to see. this is a multiple user login/checkbox system.

i.e 10 people will be able to log in and update the to-do list, then 20 users/viewers can see what progress has been made.

Getting the data from the db to be shown in a table is not a problem i have done that, i'm just having an issue with the changing the db "taskValue" from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1.

Comment: The saving code too, please, thanks.

Comment: are you saying that when you uncheck the box it doesnt work?

Comment: please provide your `post` code and DB update, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if ( count($_POST['task']) ) {
  $q = "update task_table set taskValue=0";
  mysql_query($q);

  foreach($_POST['task'] as $k=>$v) {
    $q = "update task_table set taskValue=1 where worksheetID=$k";
    mysql_query($q);
  }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
while ($seolistRow = mysql_fetch_array($seolistRes)) {
  $taskValue = $seolistRow["taskValue"];
  $worksheetID = $seolistRow["worksheetID"];
  $taskName = $seolistRow["taskName"];
  $taskInfo = $seolistRow["taskInfo"];
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="task['.$worksheetID.']" id="task_'.$worksheetID.'"'.(($taskValue)?' checked="checked"':'').' />';
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This lands you with something like:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="task[1]" id="task_1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="task[2]" id="task_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="task[3]" id="task_3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="task[4]" id="task_4" checked="checked" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The queries will automatically update the database whether the checkbox is checked or not. One page, one check/uncheck script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        var isSel = this.checked;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'urlToYourScriptThatExecuteSQL.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id : this.id,
                isSelected : isSel
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('nice');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Note: Your `urlToYourScriptThatExecuteSQL.php` receive `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['isSelected']`.